# Change the value of a field in roAssociativeArray of brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I created task and Ran it (to get the video details) when user presses watch button on the video asset. I am able to run the task and get the playback details from server. After getting play details, I need to ran a timer for every 30 sec, and once the timer is fired, I need to run another task to update the heartbeat to the server. After receiving the response for heartbeat, I need to update one field of the playback details with a value of response for heartbeat. **Even though I changed the value of field using addReplace(), the value is not getting changed.**

**scene.brs**

```
sub playLive()
    m.livePlaybackData = CreateObject("roSGNode", "FetchPlaybackDetails")
    m.livePlaybackNode.observeField("playbackDetails", "didReceivePlaybackDetails")     
    m.livePlaybackNode.control = "RUN"  
end sub

sub didReceivePlaybackDetails()
    videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
    videoContent.url = m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails.pUrl
    videoContent.title = "Test Video"
    videoContent.streamformat = "dash"

    m.video.content = videoContent
    m.video.visible = true
    m.video.setFocus(true)
    m.video.control = "play"
    m.video.observeField("state", "OnVideoPlayerStateChange")
    m.playbackHeartbeatTimer.control = "start"
    m.playbackHeartbeatTimer.ObserveField("fire","updateHeartbeat")
end sub

sub updateHeartbeat()
    m.heartbeatNode.setField("liveStreamToken", m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails.streamToken)
    m.heartbeatNode.observeField("heartbeatContent", "didReceiveHeartbeatContent")
    m.heartbeatNode.control = "RUN"
end sub

sub didReceiveHeartbeatContent()
    m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails.AddReplace("streamToken", m.heartbeatNode.heartbeatContent.streamToken)
    ?m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails.streamToken
end sub
```

In didReceiveHeartbeatContent(), I am trying to change the streamToken value in playbackDetails with streamToken of heartbeatContent. But the value is not getting changed.

playbackDetails and heartbeatContent are roAssociativeArrays I defined in XML files  and setting values as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<component name = "FetchPlaybackDetails" extends = "Task" >

<interface>
    <field id="playbackDetails" type="assocarray" />
</interface>
</component>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<component name = "UpdateHeartbeat" extends = "Task" >

<interface>
    <field id="liveStreamToken" type="string" />
    <field id="heartbeatContent" type="assocarray" />
</interface>

</component>
```

Can any one please suggest me how to change the value of a filed in the playbackDetails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative arrays as node fields are immutable, meaning that their contents cannot be changed.

You'll have to override the entire object:

```
playbackDetails = m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails
playbackDetails.streamToken = m.heartbeatNode.heartbeatContent.streamToken
m.livePlaybackNode.playbackDetails = playbackDetails
```

Or you could use Nodes instead of Associative arrays.